# Python condition statement

Tags: python-2.7

This is what I did

```
 money=raw_input("How much money do you have in your bank account?")
     if money >= 700:
         print("you have more or equal to 700")
     else money <700:
         print("you have less than 700")
```

result is 
    500, you have more or equal to 700
    800, you have more or equal to 700

The else phrase doesn't work

Comment: 1) Indent correctly. 2) `else` -> `elif`.

Comment: You might want to convert money to an integer or floating point. Input given to the raw_input function is converted to a  string and may cause your program to perform strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not mixing spaces with tabs. Also you do not need the elseif since the first condition satisfies `>=`.

```
money = raw_input("How much money do you have in your bank account?")
if money >= 700:
    print("you have more or equal to 700")
else:
    print("you have less than 700")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
 money=raw_input("How much money do you have in your bank account?")
 if money >= 700:
     print("you have more or equal to 700")
 else:
     print("you have less than 700")
```

There can't be any conditional statement after else.

Or, you can do:

```
 money=raw_input("How much money do you have in your bank account?")
 if money >= 700:
     print("you have more or equal to 700")
 elif money <700:
     print("you have less than 700")
```

Note that the second option isn't necessary becuase `else` implies that `money < 700`

Comment: When I type a 500 it should be go with else but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in just one line using one line if-else,

```
money=raw_input("How much money do you have in your bank account?")
print 'you have more or equal to 700' if money >= 700 else 'you have less than 700'
```